# cocos2d how to combine sprites

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to combine three sprites and display it as a single sprite.
I created a empty sprite and added parts but doesn't work properly.

```
    CCNode *stars = [CCNode node];

    CCSprite *star1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"star.png"];
    star1.position = ccp(-10, 0);
    [stars addChild:star1];

    CCSprite *star2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"star.png"];
    star2.position = ccp(0, 0);
    [stars addChild:star2];

    CCSprite *star3 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"star.png"];
    star3.position = ccp(10, 0);
    [stars addChild:star3];

    [self addChild:stars];
```

and I got the following exception

erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid spriteFrameName: star.png'

please help me to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding the single sprite like this:

```
CCSprite *star1 = [CCSprite **spriteWithFile**:@"star.png"];
star1.position = ccp(-10, 0);
[self addChild:star1];
```

It sounds to me like you are trying to use sprite frames but you haven't loaded any sprite sheets properly or you mean to use `spriteWithFile`.

```
CCNode *stars = [CCNode node];

CCSprite *star1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"star.png"];
star1.position = ccp(-10, 0);
[stars addChild:star1];

CCSprite *star2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"star.png"];
star2.position = ccp(0, 0);
[stars addChild:star2];

CCSprite *star3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"star.png"];
star3.position = ccp(10, 0);
[stars addChild:star3];

[self addChild:stars];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is something wrong with the .png file. Make sure that you have added it to the resources for your project.

Comment: thank you for the reply.I have added the star.png file in to Resources and I can display it as a normal sprite.